# How to prevent the UI elements overlapping from each other when the browser is resized?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I've spent the last week learning how to design a UI through HTML. I basically thought I had everything perfect with my website layout and was ready to demo.But I accidentally resized my web browser and observed that all the elements are getting overlapped each other(even in other machines the same behaviour).

I have googled this issue but none is helpful.Basically, am not sure where to modify the code.Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

```html
<!Document html>
<html lang="en">
<base href="file:///C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/HTML/">
<head>
    <title>This is title</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color:#FDF5E6;
        background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/HTML/bicycles.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 align="center" style="font-family: Colonna MT;font-size:50px;color:brown;position:absolute;top: 3%; left: 41%;">This is website heading</h1>
    <p style="color:DarkSalmon;position:absolute;top: 10%; left: 48%;"><i>"This is caption"</i>
    </div>
    <h2 style="color:skyblue; position:absolute;top: 20%; left: 39%;">Login</h2>
    <div style="color:Teal;position:absolute;top: 26%; left: 39%; width:300px;height:125px;border:1px solid #000;"></div>
    <form name="login" style="color:SandyBrown;font-size:larger;position:absolute;top: 27%; left: 40%;">
            Username : <input type="text" name="userid"/><br></br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="pswrd"/><br></br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:medium;background-color: #FFFF00; position:absolute;top: 95%; left: 50%;" type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
        <input style="font-size:medium;background-color: #FFFF00; position:absolute;top: 95%; left: 75%;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
    <a style="color:MediumVioletRed;position:absolute;bottom: 58%; left: 50.5%;" href="Forgot Password">Forgot Password</a>
    <p style="color:YellowGreen;font-size:20px;position:absolute;bottom: 53%; left: 39%;">Don't have an account?</p>
    <a style="color:Purple ;font-size:20px;position:absolute;bottom: 55%; left: 50.5%;" href="Signup.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'Signup')">Sign up</a>
    <p style="font-size:20px;position:absolute;bottom: 53%; left: 54.5%;">here</p>

    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> 
         function popup (mylink, windowname) { 
            if (! window.focus)
                return true; 
            var href; 
            if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') 
                href=mylink; 
            else 
                href=mylink.href; 
            window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); 
            return false; 
        } 
    </SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This happens because of "position:absolute"

Comment: Please Used Responsive Media Queries - http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: I think Rahul has a long way to go before using media queries

Comment: @Timo : If I removed the "Position:absoulte" then all the elements are left-aligned and the UI distorted.

Comment: They overlap because of position:absolute. UI is distorted because it is not structured well

Comment: Media queries is the best bet if you want to achieve responsiveness... media queries is simpler than it looks

Comment: You should not use so many different colors. You should not position so many elements with absolute. You could create a parent div and position it absolute. You should not add css styling in html. You should create CSS file and then style classes and add classes to your html elements. You should be more careful when writing your code, at the moment you have so many redundant code. There is a random </div> in the middle of the code, input has classes btn btn-primary which are not defined, href="Forgot Password" is not propably valid and etc

Comment: I completely agree. Because, this is my first html..But unfortunately, cannot restructure due to lack of knowledge. Could you please post the code so that I can learn and understand where I did mistakes. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple solution for you. I did not style it much, but you should be able to do this by yourself.

```js
/**
*    JS / jQuery
*/
$('#btn-login').on('click', function(){
 alert('Do login');
});

$('#btn-cancel').on('click', function(){
 $('.login-form')[0].reset();
});
```

```css
/**
*    CSS
*/
.login-box{
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.login-box a{
  display: block;
  text-align: right
}

.login-form input,
.login-form .btn{
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.button-container{
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2">
      <h1 class="text-center">The website heading</h1>
      <p class="lead text-center">"This is caption"</p>

      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="login-box">
        <form action="post" class="login-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
          </div>
          <div class="button-container text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn-login">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used bootstrap framework for css as I think it is the fastest way for beginners to create responsive mobile-first design. You can visit their [website](http://getbootstrap.com/) for more information.

I used jQuery for javascript, although I did not use it much.

In order to keep your code clean, readable and well organized, you should keep your html, css, javascript separated. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks alot.  I have learnt something new.I used the code you posted by adding some style to it..However, all the elements are left-aligned and not center-positioned. Working on it. If you can help on this, it would be great!!

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you can add a class "text-center" to an element   which contents you would like to be center aligned. Current solution is center aligned for big screens and if the screen is smaller it adjusts accordingly making the elements nearly full screen width.

Comment: I have developed it the way I wanted now. But only one thing I couldnt achieve , reducing the text boxes(username and password") size. Please let me know how can I do that. Also, I have added one more tag for inserting "Don't have an account? Signup here". but it's not appearing as expected. Here it is ...       <a href="#">Forgot password</a>
  <p>Don't have an account?<a href="#">Sign up</a>here</p>

Comment: You can modify them by adding rules to your css file. Like that: label{font-size:12px; font-weight:normal}

Comment: If am not wrong, I think you are talking about the labels but not the boxes width. Also, please give suggestions on the above edited comment i.e, "Don't have an account....." Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle in jsfiddle.net and paste the url here, so I could see your code.

Comment: Please use this url : https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_16/24cs5wvt/1/  and lemme know if it's working or not.

Comment: I replied.Please check

Answer (score 1):

You are using `position: absolute;` that's why your elements overlap when You re-size the view port. You should not be using this property for this kind of layout. Instead You should be using something like `float: left;`. And I would recommend You to look deeper into website layouts, grid models and bootstrap.

[Div positioning examples](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/788/understanding_zindex_02.png)

`float: left;` makes the div align to the left side.

`float: right;` - aligns the div the right.

And `position: absolute;` makes them float around like a balloon, and lets You choose it's position.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aivaras. Can you please tell me how do I appear at the centre of the screen exactly.

Comment: What You want to do is make one div position: absolute; and only then put your other divs inside. I made an example https://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/v0mrwqs2/4/

Comment: If I helped You, don't forget to tag my response as the answer to Your question :)

Comment: Thank you. I have combined your example and the code given by Timo. Though, i was able to make the elements appear at the required position, they are getting overlapped if the browser is resized.

Comment: I don't have much time to write a fully responsive answer. But the trick is to use percentage values in width, height, margins and etc., so when the view-port scales down the elements would scale down too. Or You can use view-port specific css with the help of "media queries". Basically the short answer to Your problem is "Responsive design". Personally for responsive Html / Css markup i try to use something like Bootstrap or Foundation. They already have responsive grids and it's very easy to achieve the result You are looking for.